# Cordova android release build jar verification warnings

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using cordova to build an android app. Now I want to release it hence I have generated the keys,etc using https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

On running

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

i am getting the following errors

at the beginning of the output for this i get

```
[certificate is valid from 9/11/15 3:29 PM to 27/3/43 3:29 PM]
      [CertPath not validated: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors]
```

at the end of the output

```
jar verified.

Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2043-03-27) or after any future revocation date.
```

What do I do here?

Comment: i have jdk1.8.0_60.jdk

Comment: Cordova is NOT a *Phonegap Build* issue. Use the tag `phonegap` or `Cordova`

Answer (score 0):

To include a timestamp you have  to sign your app with your private key like this

```
jarsigner -verbose -tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my.apk my_alias
```

You must add the path to your keystore in order to use correct entries.

```
jarsigner -verify -keystore /path_to_my/key.keystore   my_application.apk
```

Comment: Can you explain the definition of the above command for understanding?

Comment: [link]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html The jarsigner command has a -keystore option for specifying the URL of the keystore to be used. The keystore is by default stored in a file named .keystore in the user's home directory, as determined by the user.home system property.